# svn move project to a different folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

so, i have a project in some path /main/oldProject/ with trunk, and branches folders within. I  need to move the trunk and branches folder to a new one called /main/newProject/. I already imported an empty /main/newProject/ folder with TortoiseSVN but i don't know how to move all the contents from the existing folders.

i thought that svn export would do the trick but then i noticed that this will not move uncommitted changes. This is workable for me, but i was hoping there was a way to just copy the folders in the new one and run some operation that will let me work on the new path

any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I take it that this move is within a single repository? If so, checkout the repository to a local working copy somewhere and simply drag the trunk & branches folders in Windows Explorer using the right mouse button instead of the left. When you release, a dialog box will appear and give you the option of an SVN Move or an SVN Copy. Choose whichever is appropriate in your case and commit.

This will perform a proper SVN copy/move with full history.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, the best place to move a project folder within a repository is the repository browser. In the Tortoise context menu for the working copy of the folder which you want to move, choose "Repo-browser". In the Repository Browser dialog window locate the folder in the tree pane (on the left side of the window) and drag the folder to the destination folder in the tree. Tortoise will ask you to confirm and then to commit the move.

Comment: please also add the dragging part that we have to select folder and press right click (don't release right click) hold it pressed and then drag to folder in which you want to copy or move it.